# What is the difference between MySQL LIMIT range of 0,500 and 1, 500?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

If I want in MySQL rows 1 through 500, should I use LIMIT 0, 500 or LIMIT, 1, 500? What is the difference? Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The first one starts from the first record of the whole result, while the second one starts on the second record of the result.

Consider the following records

```
ID
1 -- index of the first record is zero.
2
3
4
5
6
```

if you execute

```
LIMIT 0, 3
-- the result will be ID: 1,2,3

LIMIT 1, 3
-- the result will be ID: 2,3,4
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92fea/7)

OTHER(s)

- [Limit - MySQL Command (*for more info*)](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

Comment: Is LIMIT 0,500 the same as LIMIT 500 then?

Comment: @Edward yes. it is the the same.

Comment: Thanks. 

OK, let's say I want to start on row 500, should it be LIMIT 500, 5000 or should it be LIMIT 499, 5000?

Comment: it should be `LIMIT 499, 5000`. because you have specified the duration. here's the point, if you are using `LIMIT X`, *X* there is the totalNumber of rows, while in `LIMIT X, Y`, *X* is the index of row while *Y* is the totalNumber of records.

Comment: Does MySQL guaranty the sequence of records in the record set though? I would not rely on LIMIT without ORDER BY or WHERE.

Comment: @Bulat if no `ORDER BY` was supplied on the query, the default sort order will be by the the *KEYS* define, eg. *PRIMARY KEY*

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL, the meaning of LIMIT n1, n2 is :

```
n1 : starting index
n2 : number of record/data you want to show
```

For example :

```
ID
-------------------------
1  ------------ > index 0
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10 ------------ > index 9
```

Now if you write query like

```
SELECT * from tbl_name LIMIT 0,5
Output : 
1
2
3
4
5
```

And if you write query like

```
SELECT * from tbl_name LIMIT 2,7
Output : 
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 0):

@JohnWoo That's not correct. The order of rows from a `SELECT` statement, with no `ORDER BY` clause, is unspecified. Therefore even though by visually looking at the output order of such a query it may seem to be in a specific order, that order is not guaranteed and therefore not reliable. If you require a result set to be ordered in a certain way you must use an `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

### ID

1
2
3
4
5 ------------ > index 0
6
7
8
9 ------------ > after 5 index add 4 value
10

If you want data from 5 to 9 so query should be

SELECT * from table_name LIMIT 5,4

Comment: does this really answer the question? can you make it clear using OP's example please